# ¿Como podría traducir la palabra "portable" de inglés a castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, informática, inglés

En inglés, en el contexto de ordenadores/programación, *portable* se usa para describir un programa o un comando que se puede ejecutar en distintos sistemas. Por ejemplo, un programa que puede ser ejecutado tanto en Windows como en Linux.

En el mundo de Unix/Linux, también se usa para describir que algo es estándar y uno puede esperar que funcione en cualquier sistema *nix. Un ejemplo sería:

> The -o option of grep is not **portable**, not all grep versions have it.

Como podría decir lo mismo en castellano?

> La opción -o del grep no es portable*, no la tienen todas las versiones de grep.

*Portable* no puede ser correcto (al menos que yo sepa), ya que ninguna de sus definiciones me parece relevante. RAE [dice](https://dle.rae.es/portable):

> 1. adj. [portátil](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Tl21X5Z#CfMZesC). Reloj portable.

Y, para [*portátil*](https://dle.rae.es/port%C3%A1til#CfMZesC):

> 1. adj. Movible y fácil de transportar.
> 2. m. ordenador portátil.

Tampoco me ayuda mucho [Wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=portable):

> portable adj  (computing: compatible) compatible adj mf

Pero *compatible* necesita un objeto específico, ¿no es cierto? Algo no puede ser "compatible" en general, ha de ser compatible *con* algo. ¿Cómo podría decir en castellano que algo es "portable", es decir que se puede usar en distintos sistemas operativos sin especificar cuáles? ¿Puedo decir *compatible*? ¿Existe otra palabra?

Comment: Me equivoqué en un detalle: un portable es francés para un teléfono móvil. Desculpa.

Comment: Con todo el cuidado que intento tener con estas cosas, a veces se me escapa una o otra. :)

Comment: ¿_transportable_?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' si no estas seguro tu, no se. ¿El _portable_ no te suena bien? Ademas de los ejemplos en la respuesta de lambie, [también pregunté en SO.es chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/conversation/portabilidad) y dos usuarios me dijeron que ellos si que lo usarían o que lo han visto. ¿Tu que eres un buen friki de *nix, no lo dirías?

Comment: @terdon es que nunca en la vida lo dije en castellano, siempre lo usé en inglés :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Usar la metodología de HLS permite desarrollar algoritmos en alto
> nivel, disminuyendo el tiempo de desarrollo y validando la correcta
> funcionalidad del diseño más rápidamente, controlar la síntesis
> mediante directivas de optimización (los pragmas HLS nombrados
> previamente) y la  **creación de códigos fuente en C comprensibles y portables a diferentes dispositivos.**

[portable en español para portable en inglés](https://ebuah.uah.es/dspace/bitstream/handle/10017/43936/TFG_Montalvo_Rodrigo_2020.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Se dice también *trasladable*:

> El FDP es un entorno de programación que se ha desarrollado para un
> IBM PC, AT, 386 o compatible, aunque es fácilmente trasladable a otras
> máquinas, por ejemplo workstations
> [trasladable](https://webs.um.es/jmgarcia/miwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=esc-ver.pdf)

El inglés utiliza *portable* también para lo que en español se dice *portátil*.

A no confundir: *portable* en inglés para algo portátil, que se puede llevar en la mano o los brazos fácilmente, y *portable* en inglés con la idea de traslado o ejecución de una programación de una plataforma a/en otra, por ejemplo.

WIKIPEDIA:
[portabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidad#:%7E:text=Se%20define%20como%20la%20caracter%C3%ADstica,plataformas%20y%2Fo%20sistemas%20operativos.)

> La 'portabilidad' es uno de los conceptos clave en la programación de
> alto nivel.
>
> Se define como la característica que posee un software para ejecutarse
> en diferentes plataformas, es decir, la portabilidad se refiere
> exclusivamente a la propiedad que posee un software que le permite ser
> ejecutado en diferentes plataformas y/o sistemas operativos.

Comment: Tu primer ejemplo, lo de la tesis, es exactamente lo que quiero. Lo único que me preocupa es que mismo en este contexto tan académico y técnico, el autor se sentió obligado a clarificar "portables *a diferentes dispositivos" cosa que me hace pensar que no puedo simplemente decir que "foo no es portable". No por incorrecto, sino porque quizás no va a ser entendido. Pero si que parece ser la palabra correcta, en todo caso. Gracias!

Comment: Si, hijo (no te preocupas, soy vieja :)), pero también viene en el artïculo de Wikipedia.

Comment: Creo que el autor del primer texto podía haberse ahorrado ese *a diferentes dispositivos* sin ningún problema. La palabra *portable* es de uso habitual en este contexto y significa, simplemente, lo que indica el sufijo `-able`: que se puede portar. El diccionario tiende a no definir palabras formadas por derivación cuando su significado es, simplemente, el que indican sus elementos compositivos.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar tal cual, ya que está admitida directamente en el Diccionario de la Academia:

> **Portable**. Portátil.

Comment: Gracias (y gracias por la mejora de la pregunta!) pero esta definición no ayuda mucho. [La RAE defina](https://www.rae.es/dpd/port%C3%A1til) _portátil_ como ‘Movible y fácil de transportar’, y aquí se trata de otro sentido. Estoy buscando una palabra técnica para un concepto técnico y bastante específico.

Comment: Yo la proponía precisamente porque una aplicación *portable* es *movible* entre diferentes sistemas operativos, y *fácil de transportar*, porque la puedes llevar en un dispositivo USB, por ejemplo. Así es como uso yo un montón de aplicaciones *portables*.